How do I open this Chamberlain Garage Door Wall Control?
I would like to open this so I can interface it with my ESPHome device. There are slots along the sides, but I don't want to go willy-nilly jamming screwdrivers and start trying to pry the cover off without knowing for sure and breaking something. I can't find the manual for this model which matches. It's the Chamberlain Whisper Quiet +.
There's a slot on each side:



I finally figured it out. The large door open/close button at the top has a screw under it. CAREFULLY pry this button off. It's held on with 4 locking tabs, two on the top and two on the bottom. It's not clear if the top or bottom should be removed first, or if it matters.
Once off, you'll see the screw going through the unit that goes into your electrical box. Remove that. The bottom screw is a slotted hole, so simply lift up on the unit and that unlocks the bottom screw.
The slots on the side of the case are there so you can route wires out from any of the 4 sides tight to the drywall.
